# Does heat increase the hydrolysis of urea hydrochloride?

Tags: organic-chemistry, heat

The preparation of ammonium chloride by reacting urea with HCl produce urea hydrochloride the reaction take too much time to get ammonium chloride depending on ratios.

[image]

So can heat increase the process?

Comment: Thermodynamically or kinetically? For the latter, it speeds up all processes. Some more than others, so it can shift equilibrium both ways.

Comment: I have cropped your image to highlight the relevant text but it's better to write the text as [pictures are not searchable.](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3758/policy-on-picture-questions/3799)

Comment: You may look [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.molcatb.2009.01.003) to understand the reaction.